# invalid regular expression flag a

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, silex

I use Silex Frame Work and I am trying to delete files in backend that listed in a table using the following code but fire bug is given me an error message "invalid regular expression flag a" And when i click on the DELETE link it goes to a white page.The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".delete-file").live('click', function() {
            itemRow   = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
            fileId    = $(this).attr('file_id');
            deleteURL = $(this).attr('href');

            var html   = "<div> Are you sure, you want to DELETE this file? </div>";
            var dialog = $(html).dialog({
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            url     : deleteURL,
                            type    : 'DELETE',
                            success : function(data) {
                                itemRow.remove();
                                dialog.dialog("close");
                            },
                            error   : function() {
                                dialog.dialog("close");
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    "Cancel": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

and i use:

```
   {% for row in result %}
       <tr class="content {{ cycle(['odd', 'even'], loop.index) }}">
            <td> {{ row.name }} </td>
            <td> {{ row.user.username }} </td>
            <td class="url"> <a href="{{ path('info', {"id" : row.file_id}) }}">{{ row.path | truncate(30) }}</a> </td>
            <td> <img src="{{conf('base_url')}}/{{row.thumbnail}}"/> </td>
            <td class="url"> {{ row.size | bytes_format}} </td>
            <td> {{ row.description }} </td>
            <td>
                <span><a href="{{ path('delete', {'id' : row.file_id} ) }}" class="delete-file" file-id="{{row.file_id}}">DELETE</a></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: invalid regular expression flag a
[Break On This Error]  

    /home/saeed/www/karina/moshare/web/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js
  ...  jquery.min.js (line 1, col 6)

Comment: Fire Bug also show me this error:

$ is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

$(document).ready(function(){

Comment: Where is the regular expression?  This is a JS regular expression: /[a-z]\w+/gi.  The gi at the end are flags, g=global, i=ignore case.  It says you have 'a', somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. it's just because of giving wrong path to my .js files!!